# How can I disable row selection toggling in Kendo Angular Grid?

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

The default row selection behaviour for the Kendo Angular grid is to toggle the selection - that is, clicking a selected (highlighted) row will deselect it (remove the highlighting), according to the [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/selection/).

I want the selected row to remain highlighted if it is clicked repeatedly. I have been unable to find anything in the documentation that would suggest that this is possible, yet it seems like a reasonable requirement (a situation in which there must always be a row selected).

Is there perhaps a built-in, undocumented way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your project is Angular 2+.
You could disable interaction with a row once it becomes selected by using the rowClass callback input. You might need to bind the Component's 'this' to the callback row to make sure you can get your Component keys into the callback. Something like:

Template:

```
<kendo-grid [rowClass]="selectionToggleCallback" [selectedKeys]="keys">
```

Component:

```
keys:Array<number> = [];
ngOnInit(){
  this.selectionToggleCallback = this.selectionToggleCallback.bind(this);
}

selectionToggleCallback(context:RowClassArgs){
  const isDisabled = this.keys.includes(context.index);
  return { 'k-disabled' : isDisabled };
}
```

Comment: I accepted this as I have had no other answers and I appreciate your taking the time to post it. We went with another grid in the end that has better functionality.

Comment: @MarkFarr Which grid did you choose ?

Comment: @indra257My apologies for such a delayed response (2 years, wow). It was a grid developed in-house by our framework team. It did not have better functionality over all, just better for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The suggested answer simply does not work for me. the class is applied but `k-disabled` does nothing. I used the alternative `pointer-events: none` css property to achieve the same.